# How to tell Borland C++ that an enum is inside a class?

Tags: c++, enums, namespaces, turbo-c++, borland-c++

One of my assignments requires that my code compiles with no error on Borland Turbo C++. Problem is, I have a class called **OAConfiguration** that contains an enum:

```
enum HBLOCK_TYPE{hbNone, hbBasic, hbExtended, hbExternal};
```

In my code I implement the function **AllocateBlock** function for the **ObjectAllocator** class, where I have a statement like this:

```
if (OAConfig::HBLOCK_TYPE::hbExternal)
```

While this works fine in VS, Borland says that is "not a class or namespace name in  ObjectAllocator::AllocateBlock(void *)"

Could someone please point out the correct syntax, I can't manage to find similar problems elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

Borland is right in this regard: you can't qualify the enumerators by the enumeration name. Visual Studio only supports that as an extension. The correct code would be like this:

```
if (OAConfig::hbExternal)
```

In C++11, a new type `enum class` was added to the language. That offers scoped access (and scoped access only), while also not supporting the implicit conversion with `int`.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you very much. So C++11 eliminates old enums or just adds new ones ? Enums used to index a vector help make code easier to read, and make jump table calls a lot cleaner.

Comment: @user3218083 Of course old `enum`s remained a part of the language, and they I dare say they always will. That's why the new, scoped enumeration is introduced by a new keyword combination.

Comment: "Visual Studio only supports that as an extension." - unfortunately, they had the poor taste to turn it on by default.

Comment: @TonyD AFAIK, all VS extensions are turned on by default.